# How to programmatically enable and disable Flight mode on Android 4.2?

Tags: android, airplane-mode

Is there a way to disable or enable Flight Mode on Android 4.2?

I use this code that works only for previous Android versions:

```
android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(
    c.getContentResolver(),   
    android.provider.Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, enable ? 0 : 1
);
```

Answer (score 44):

There exist a simple workaround on **rooted** devices.

To enable Airplane Mode the following root shell commands can be used:

```
settings put global airplane_mode_on 1
am broadcast -a android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE --ez state true
```

To disable Airplane Mode these root shell commands can be used:

```
settings put global airplane_mode_on 0
am broadcast -a android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE --ez state false
```

Info taken from [here](http://zipta.ru/2012/11/borba-s-android-4-2/)

Disclaimer: This info is provided "as-is" without any form of warranty.

Comment: Exposed framework which may require user to install something else on their phone via computer.

Comment: Your link doesn't accessible!

Answer (score 24):

This is no longer possible, except by apps that are signed by the firmware signing key or are installed on the system partition (typically by a rooted device user).

Comment: http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/11/20/miscellaneous-android-4p2-regressions.html

Comment: omg... why everyone is having a root is a must?

Answer (score 16):

You can't, as written in [Official Android 4.2 API Documentation](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html)

> Some device settings defined by `Settings.System` are now read-only. If
>   your app attempts to write changes to settings defined in
>   `Settings.System` that have moved to `Settings.Global`, the write
>   operation will silently fail when running on Android 4.2 and higher.
>   Even if your value for `android:targetSdkVersion` and
>   `android:minSdkVersion` is lower than 17, your app is not able to modify
>   the settings that have moved to `Settings.Global` when running on
>   Android 4.2 and higher.

However, if you are the OS Developer, you can write it when you set these permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />
```

Then to write and read,

```
// To Write
Settings.Global.putString(getContentResolver(), "airplane_mode_on", "1");

// To Read
String result = Settings.Global.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON);
Toast.makeText(this, "result:"+result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Hmmmmm, but this method just add in Android 4.2

Comment: Oh, yes. It can't.

It can only if only you give the permission android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS

That's mean you must an os dev,, and I'm so I didn't notice it.

Comment: @ToonSuperLove,Are you sure these Settings.Global will write device settings airplane mode.I have an similar task to always keep air plane mode in off.reply me ASAP.

Comment: @ToonSuperLove, I tried you snippet, having problem on adding  permission WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS at manifest..Let me guide to achieve the result to disable airplane mode

Comment: @SenthilMg , did you find a solution? How can I create a **System app** and use the **WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS** permission?

Comment: What is an OS Developer exactly? Anyone who has a rooted phone? How can I get this to work?

Comment: For those that don't know how to get the permission, come here: https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml. Look for the permission. You'll notice is says (currently) "signature|privileged|development". So you either sign the app with the firmware key, you install is as a privileged app, or you keep debug mode enabled on it for the permission to be granted (hopefully I didn't make any mistake here).

Comment: what the...? Only Supported for OS Dev...? Omg... I feel a nightmare for several limitation we achieved so far in Android Dev then.

Answer (score 0):

For KitKat, you have to add `android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"` in manifest file.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.airplanesetting"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0"
    android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system" >
```

Comment: I get "installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE" from eclipse when trying to install the apk with this in there

Comment: Changing the sharedUserId won't work unless you are also signed with the same key, aka using the system's keystore