# Unable to run toggleAirplaneMode(True) python script on SL4A for Android

Tags: android, python, sl4a

I'm using SL4A and running android scripts. `.toggleAirplaneMode(True)` gives a null pointer exception.
Code:

```
import android
droid= android.Android()
droid.toggleAirplaneMode(True)
```

I have checked and found that flight mode for higher versions of Android 4.4 and above is moved to `System.Settings.Global` and cannot be accessed.
Is there an alternative way to do enable/disable flight mode in python or using python script?

Answer (score 0):

SL4A airplanemode functions are deprecated above KitKat.
And there is no java API to change airplanemode in unsinged applications (such as SL4A).

If you have rooted device, try to use os.system method:

```
su = "/system/xbin/su"  # your su binary
os.system(su + " settings put global airplane_mode_on true")
os.system(su + " am broadcast -a android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE --ez state true")
```

this is from: [How to turn on/off airplane mode, even on new Android versions (and even with root)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25674655/how-to-turn-on-off-airplane-mode-even-on-new-android-versions-and-even-with-ro)