# turn on and off airplane mode without toggle button in android

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to turn off and on airplane mode in android without toggle button.
this is my code.
when the app reached this code airplane mode should on:

```
 if (intent.getAction().equals(strAirplaneOn)){

    }
```

and when the app reaches this code airplane mode should off:

```
else if (intent.getAction().equals(strAirplaneOff)){

    }
```

Comment: So, what's stopping you from doing that? What's your question? Did you try anything?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programmatically enable and disable Flight mode on Android 4.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13766909/how-to-programmatically-enable-and-disable-flight-mode-on-android-4-2)

Comment: I tried many ways, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13766909/how-to-programmatically-enable-and-disable-flight-mode-on-android-4-2

Comment: And what happened when you tried them? What went wrong? Also, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25674655/how-to-turn-on-off-airplane-mode-even-on-new-android-versions-and-even-with-ro), it may not actually be possible on non-rooted devices anymore through "normal" APIs if I'm reading the answers correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to turn on/off airplane mode, even on new Android versions (and even with root)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25674655/how-to-turn-on-off-airplane-mode-even-on-new-android-versions-and-even-with-ro)

Comment: all stops app..

Comment: I can't use root access in my app