# How to toggle Airplane Mode on a rooted device?

Tags: java, android, android-settings

I am using following method :

```
private void toggleAirplaneMode() throws Exception {        
    // read the airplane mode setting
    boolean isEnabled = android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(
          getContentResolver(), 
          android.provider.Settings.Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) == 1;

    // toggle airplane mode
    android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(
          getContentResolver(),
          android.provider.Settings.Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, isEnabled ? 0 : 1);

    // Post an intent to reload
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
    intent.putExtra("state", !isEnabled);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

And getting following exception :

```
12-30 09:49:05.875: D/tag(5876): android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1540)
12-30 09:49:05.875: D/tag(5876): android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:185)
12-30 09:49:05.875: D/tag(5876): android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137)
12-30 09:49:05.875: D/tag(5876): android.content.ContentProviderProxy.call(ContentProviderNative.java:643)
12-30 09:49:05.875: D/tag(5876): android.provider.Settings$NameValueCache.putStringForUser(Settings.java:1094)
12-30 09:49:05.876: D/tag(5876): android.provider.Settings$Global.putStringForUser(Settings.java:6827)
12-30 09:49:05.876: D/tag(5876): android.provider.Settings$Global.putString(Settings.java:6811)
12-30 09:49:05.876: D/tag(5876): android.provider.Settings$Global.putInt(Settings.java:6905)
```

where i am getting wrong??Is there any other way out???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15861046/how-to-toggle-airplane-mode-on-android-4-2-using-root go to this link

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" /> and  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />have u added this permission

Comment: @AbhishekChaubey already added this permission

Comment: Did you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13422527/modify-airplane-mode-on-on-android-4-2-and-above?

Answer (score 1):

```
// To Write
    Settings.Global.putString(getContentResolver(), "airplane_mode_on", "1");

    // To Read
    String result = Settings.Global.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON);
    Toast.makeText(this, "result:"+result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Put String insted int
and don't forget to add permissions

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />
```

Hope it may help u

Answer (score 1):

From Android 4.2 Aeroplane mode changing intent is protected only System apps can change it.so it doesn't work for other apps.

For more check this [Aeroplane mode Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED)

below 4.2 you can chage aeroplane mode like

You can get the Aeroplane mode status like

```
public static boolean isAirplaneModeOn(Context context) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        return Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(),
                Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) != 0;
    } else {
        return Settings.Global.getInt(context.getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) != 0;
    }
}
```

You can change the aeroplane mode like

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static void switchAeroplaneMode(Context context, boolean isEnabled) {
    if (isEnabled == isAirplaneModeOn(context)) {
        return;
    }
    if (isAeroplaneModeSupports()) {
        Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(),
                Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, isEnabled ? 1 : 0);

        // Post an intent to reload.
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
        intent.putExtra("state", !isEnabled);
        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}

public static boolean isAeroplaneModeSupports() {
    return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1;
}
```

And add Permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

Comment: so you mean above 4.2 i can not change airplane mode?? And I have rooted device.

Comment: @user2014 for rooted device you can change..check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13766909/how-to-programmatically-enable-and-disable-flight-mode-on-android-4-2/15877584#15877584