# Android Kitkat 4.4.2 - How to set PACKAGE_VERIFIER_ENABLE hidden API attribute?

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm looking to set the Verify Apps attribute under Settings >> Security on my Android device either through a custom APK or via the ADB terminal.

I found a process for enabling hidden/internal API settings [here](https://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-1-introduction/), however Eclipse will not allow me to compile my APK.

The call that I am making in my MainActivity is:

```
Settings.Secure.putInt(MainActivity.this.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.PACKAGE_VERIFIER_ENABLE, 0);
```

I saw in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15877584/4244753) that a broadcast receiver may be used via the adb shell. Is it possible to set hidden/internal API settings using this method?

Either method would work on my end for accomplishing this task, but it would be nice to know both methods, if they exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable

```
settings put global package_verifier_enable 0
```

To Enable

```
settings put global package_verifier_enable 1
```