# how to enable and disable the offline mode automatically from app in react-native

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to enable and disable the offline mode automatically in android using react-native code,
I want to know whether is there any possibility like that in react-native,
If possible can any one give me suggestions that how can i achieve it.
 Any help must be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you want to handling Offline and online status in React Native ?

Comment: @Deva yes i want to handle offline and online status of aeroplane mode(flight mode)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programmatically enable and disable Flight mode on Android 4.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13766909/how-to-programmatically-enable-and-disable-flight-mode-on-android-4-2)

Answer (score 1):

Try this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-system-setting

```
  import SystemSetting from 'react-native-system-setting'

       SystemSetting.isAirplaneEnabled().then((enable)=>{
        const state = enable ? 'On' : 'Off';
        console.log('Current airplane is ' + state);
    })

    SystemSetting.switchAirplane(()=>{
        console.log('switch airplane successfully');
    })
```

Comment: this is for only checking whether Airplane mode is disabled or enabled but i want to set it enable and disable from my code only, not opening the settings screen.

Comment: this is just a check

Answer (score 0):

cannot switch since 4.2 version

```
If your app is currently making changes to settings previously defined in Settings.System (such as AIRPLANE_MODE_ON), then you should expect that doing so will no longer work on a device running Android 4.2 or higher
```

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2

Answer (score -1):

You can use the react native Netinfo to find the device ofline and online. Refer the below link 
https://medium.com/dailyjs/offline-notice-in-react-native-28a8d01e8cd0

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { View, Text, NetInfo, Dimensions, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');

function MiniOfflineSign() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.offlineContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.offlineText}>No Internet Connection</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

class OfflineNotice extends PureComponent {
  state = {
    isConnected: true
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener('connectionChange', this.handleConnectivityChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    NetInfo.isConnected.removeEventListener('connectionChange', this.handleConnectivityChange);
  }

  handleConnectivityChange = isConnected => {
    if (isConnected) {
      this.setState({ isConnected });
    } else {
      this.setState({ isConnected });
    }
  };

  render() {
    if (!this.state.isConnected) {
      return <MiniOfflineSign />;
    }
    return null;
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  offlineContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#b52424',
    height: 30,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    width,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 30
  },
  offlineText: { color: '#fff' }
});

export default OfflineNotice;
```

Comment: thank you for your response, but i want to enable and disable the aeroplane mode from react-native code.  NetInfo is for checking the network connection only know?

Comment: this is just a check