# How to code Enable and Disable Wifi, Mobile Data and GPS by one same switch?

Tags: java, android

How to code Enable and Disable Wifi, Mobile Data and GPS by one same switch in android studio ?
I've found a code that only enable and disable wifi by switch. But I'm looking for a code of android studio that enable and disable Wifi, Mobile Data and GPS by one same switch in the same time.

```
package com.pc.ibms.helptechattendancescanner;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.Switch;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    Switch aSwitch;
    WifiManager wifiManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        aSwitch=(Switch)findViewById(R.id.myswitch);
        wifiManager = (WifiManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
        //register the switch for event handling
        aSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked && !wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()){
                    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
                }
                //to switch off wifi
                else if(!isChecked && wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()){
                    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Main Activity**

```
package com.pc.ibms.helptechattendancescanner;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.Switch;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    Switch aSwitch;
    WifiManager wifiManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        aSwitch=(Switch)findViewById(R.id.myswitch);
        wifiManager = (WifiManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
        //register the switch for event handling
        aSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked && !wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()){
                    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
                }
                //to switch off wifi
                else if(!isChecked && wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()){
                    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Android Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pc.ibms.helptechattendancescanner">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/App_Name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>


**Activity Main**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <Switch
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/myswitch"
        android:text="WiFi Setting"
        android:textOn="ON"
        android:textOff="OFF"
        android:showText="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If you are writing the ROM https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13766909/how-to-programmatically-enable-and-disable-flight-mode-on-android-4-2